# adding 2 XML strings together in XQuery

Tags: xml, string, xquery

I'm trying to create an xml output of some items, which works perfect, though when i try to add a blabla tag in front of it fails.

I think it's rather easy, but I'm not able to find a solution.

the code i'm using:

```
let $data := content:sortContent(content:retrieveLastFM() union content:retrieveYoutube() union content:retrieveImgur() union content:retrieveFlickr() union content:retrieveNYTimes() union content:retrieveDiggTechnology() union content:retrieveDiggAmusement()),

$doc := <description>Blablabla</description> <items> {$data} </items>

return $doc
```

The following does work:

```
$doc := <items>{$data}</items>
```

Though I want a description in front of my list of items..

I hope you understand what I'm trying to reach here ;)
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would not output valid XML. Depending on what you want to get, there are two possibilities:

Wrap the element in some **container element** to return valid XML:

```
$doc := <container><description>Blablabla</description> <items> {$data} </items></container>
```

Which returns

```
<container>
  <description>Blablabla</description>
  <items>somedata</items>
</container>
```

---

Or you could return a **sequence of XML nodes**:

```
$doc := (<description>Blablabla</description>, <items> {$data} </items>)
```

Which returns

```
<description>Blablabla</description>
<items>1</items>
<description>Blablabla</description>
<items>2</items>
<description>Blablabla</description>
<items>3</items>
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to assign a sequence of nodes to `$doc`, this has to be done explicitly via `,`:

```
let $data := ...,
    $doc  := (<description>Blablabla</description>, <items> {$data} </items>)
return $doc
```

Another possibility is to wrap both nodes inside another element or a `document` node (as the variable name suggests anyway):

```
    $doc  := <doc><description>Blablabla</description><items> {$data} </items></doc>
```

or

```
    $doc  := document { <description>Blablabla</description>, <items> {$data} </items> }
```